# Return Pdf Docs from Controller in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: pdf-generation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I tried to get Pdf Docs from my IActionResult method using APIs like RazorPdf,MvcPdfActionResult,PerfectPdf... But none is working for me. I am Developing an Application in ASP.NET Core MVC.

Are there any supported APIs for generating Pdfs from Controller Actions....?

Comment: If you found a solution, post it as answer and mark it as accepted. Do not update your question with the solution!

Comment: Thank @Tseng I am new to StackOverflow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MvcPdfActionResult worked for me with... I just had to change the ViewName.

Instead of passing it directly, I tried giving it's relative path like ~/Views/PdfView.cshtml.

The actual code looks like this...

```
return new PdfActionResult("~/Views/PdfView.cshtml", modelobject)
```